# List of String Insert method increases its size

Tags: vb.net, list, linked-list, insert

Here is the code

```
    Public Class FrmPatientFolder 

Dim tab1RTBtext As List(Of String)
Dim comboboxprevious As Integer
Dim comboboxcurrent As Integer

Private Sub FrmPatientFolder_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

'this contains 12 string which are too long to include in code
tab1combolist = New List(Of String)(New String() {"1",..to..,"12"}

ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(tab1combolist.ToArray)
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

comboboxprevious = -1
comboboxcurrent = 0

'this performs a select query that either returns a list of 12 strings or nothing
tab1RTBtext = selectFromTable(New List(Of String)(New String() {"*"}), "chronicle", "amka", Me.Text)


If tab1RTBtext Is Nothing Then
tab1RTBtext = New List(Of String)
tab1RTBtext.Add(Me.Text)

For Each item In tab1combolist
tab1RTBtext.Add("")
Next

insertNewPatientIntoTable("chronicle", tab1RTBtext)
tab1RTBtext.RemoveAt(0)

Else         
tab1RTBtext.RemoveAt(0)
RichTextBox1.Rtf = tab1RTBtext(0)

End If

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

     If comboboxprevious <> -1 Then
        comboboxprevious = comboboxcurrent
        comboboxcurrent = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex

    Else
        comboboxcurrent = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
        comboboxprevious = comboboxcurrent
    End If

    If comboboxcurrent <> comboboxprevious And comboboxprevious <> -1 Then

        Console.WriteLine(tab1RTBtext.Count)
        Console.WriteLine(comboboxprevious & tab1RTBtext(comboboxprevious))

        tab1RTBtext.Insert(comboboxprevious, RichTextBox1.Rtf.ToString)
        Console.WriteLine(tab1RTBtext.Count)
        Console.WriteLine(comboboxprevious & tab1RTBtext(comboboxprevious))
        RichTextBox1.Rtf = tab1RTBtext(comboboxcurrent).ToString
    End If

End Sub


End Sub
```

and this is what happens if select the second item of combobox at runtime

```
12
0
13
0{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1253\deff0\deflang1032{\fonttbl{\f\fnil\fcharset161 Trebuchet MS;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs24\par
}
```

So I'm telling the list, that if the index of the combobox changed, to store the richtextbox.rtf at the index of the previous combobox item. And yet every time the insert method is being called, it increases the list size. Why is this happening??? Besides that, when I change the selected item in the combobox, it doesn't do what it's supposed to, it doesn't display the correct values which means that the list's size doesn't expand from the end but from the insertion point?

Maybe the handling of rtf is wrong here and I should check for formatting with empty string, then clear the contents before storing but I can't imagine how this could have any effect to the problem I'm facing.

I read here https://www.dotnetperls.com/list-insert that the list class is optimized for the add method, and If one wants to use insert instead, should consider using the linkedlist class, but If I were to do that then I would have to adapt my code in many other places.

Comment: Well I'm stupid... insert shouldn't be used in this case... I should directly place the value inside my list at the previous index... no wonder Noone wants to state the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
tab1RTBtext.Insert(comboboxprevious, RichTextBox1.Rtf.ToString)
```

into

```
tab1RTBtext(comboboxprevious) = RichTextBox1.Rtf.ToString
```

and this is what happens when you make assumptions about how a method works. I hope you had a good laugh, or giggle at least. :)